# materialize css modal loop in ng-repeat is not working

Tags: css, materialize

Below is my sample code according to this guide http://materializecss.com/modals.html. Individual modals are working fine but as loop its not working. I was tried with ng-repeat $index for getting unique modal'ID

```
<tr ng-repeat="u in users">
    <td>{{ $index +1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ u.first_name +" "+ u.last_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ u.email }}</td>
    <td>{{ u.plan }}</td>
    <td>
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" data-target="modal1" href="#modal{{$index+1}}">
        Remove
        </a>
        <div id="modal{{$index+1}}" class="modal bottom-sheet">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h4>Modal Header</h4>
                <p>A bunch of text</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Should you use the $index in `data-target` as well?

Comment: yes that also added,  
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" data-target="modal{{$index+1}}" href="#modal{{$index+1}}">
                                        Remove
                                    </a>

Comment: as a individual its working fine, But in loop its not if any example provide the sample

Comment: Post some more code or a plunker so that we can help.

Comment: here is the link of plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/4l1yLs6qtmCXyTbK0Akp?p=catalogue

Comment: Were you able to get a solution for this? I'm in a similar situation where I need to use materialize and construct something using ng-repeat. It works without the ng-repeat but doesn't with it!